# Increment `int i = 0` to increment in the position of an initialized char array

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a char variable:

```
int i = 0;
char currentByte = (*(char*)((intptr_t)bytes + i));
```

Longer down in the code, I want to change `currentByte` depending on the number of `i`. How would I go on about this in C++?

I wanted to do something like this:

```
// Go through bytes, and go to next byte:
i++;
```

To then change `currentByte` from

```
char currentByte = (*(char*)((intptr_t)bytes + 0));
```

to

```
char currentByte = (*(char*)((intptr_t)bytes + 1));
```

What I wanted to achieve was to not have to write "(*(char*)((intptr_t)bytes + i))" everywhere in my code. Sorry my C++ is rusty.

Comment: One way to not write duplicate code is to write a function.

Comment: How is `bytes` defined? And why not just use `bytes[i]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are your friends:

```
char GetByte(int pos)
{
    return (char*)((intptr_t)bytes + pos);
}
```

And, perhaps, depending on the scope of your `i`:

```
char GetCurrentByte()
{
    return GetByte(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `bytes` already a byte array?

```
char* pCurrentByte = &bytes[0]; // or i
pCurrentByte++; // Now at (bytes + 1)

char currentByte = *pCurrentByte;
```